# How do you determine the amount of bits for the tag, index, and offset in a MIPS byte-addressed direct-mapped cache when given only a list of address?

Tags: cpu, cpu-cache, mips, cache

The question I'm working on is as follows:

[image: Question]

I'm still kind of working on how direct-mapped caches work in my computer organization class.
I sort of understand that you need the least significant 2 bits to address which byte to use in a word (4 bytes), but that's about as far as I can get with this question.
I don't know how many blocks are in the cache, so I don't know how to get the number of index bits, and I don't know how many bits are needed to address each word or whatever.

I've been here for like 1.5 hours and I can't figure it out.